# How to apply a sliding window for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I use the following function to apply a sliding window on a list. how can I do the similar to a dataframe?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = list(range(36))
window_size = 12
splits = []

for i in range(window_size, len(data)):
    train = np.array(data[i-window_size:i])
    test = np.array(data[i:i+3])
    splits.append(('TRAIN:', train, 'TEST:', test))
```

for example

```
pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(36, 1))
```

Comment: One simple solution is to replace `data` by the dataframe indices, and then apply the same function you are using

Comment: ok got it. thanks. Also, can I just remove np.array from the code?

Comment: Sure. You are just slicing lists anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a bit messy because I didnt use an original dataset. But this should give you an idea.

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    window_size=[2,2]
    for x in range(window_size[0]):
       for y in range(window_size[1]):
           train=df[0:x].loc[0:y]
           print(train.head())
           test=df[x:].loc[y:]
           print(test.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

Slicing dataframes with iloc may make it fairly simple :

```
df.iloc[:,2:]
```

above will yield all rows for 3rd column onwards (skipped first two columns)

```
df.iloc[:,3:5]
```

above will yield column 4th and 5th

and so on

Hope it helps

Comment: Similar operation possible on rows (i.e. specifying ranges around first colon)